# Ad Network CPC/CPM Bidding Formula?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I apologize if my question is not well structured, but English is not my first language.

From my university I received a personal quest to create an ad network (in PHP, MySQL and JavaScript), similar to google.com/adwords + google.com/adsense.

AdWords is a place where any company can add its ads and pay a price for showing up in the AdSense network.

AdSsense is a place from which each site owner can take a unique code to put on his site and earn commission from it (every click and impression).

The problem is that I can not create a formula for ad's price bidding - CostPerClick [CPC] (https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2464960?hl=en) and CostPerThousandImpressions [CPM] (https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6310?hl=en).

I can't understand - how their system calculates which ad will show up frist and how often it will be shown?

**Example:**

```
1. Shoes Market (Type: CPC, Max Bid: $0.25)

2. Computer Store (Type: CPC, Max Bid: $0.50)

3. Pharmaceutical Store (Type: CPM, Max Bid: $0.43)

4. Dog Treats (Type: CPC, Max Bid: $1.00)
```

Comment: Of course, these pricing formulae and algorithms are commercial secrets. They are also the product of hundreds of skilled people working for years. The challenge in your project is to work out a minimally viable way to balance advert supply and demand, not to replicate Google.  You'll be wise to work it out from first principles such as the balance of revenue and payments.